# Why would an akka router be sending messages to dead letters after startup?

Tags: scala, akka

Shortly after my app starts up I see this in the logs:

```
INFO  akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef - Message [java.lang.String] from   Actor[akka://MyApp/user/sqs-poller/router#-923782747] to Actor[akka://MyApp/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Does this mean the router was sent a shutdown command? Is it possible to have akka log the dead letters?

Answer (score 0):

This type of dead-letters warnings are often harmless as described in the [Akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html#Logging_of_Dead_Letters).  As illustrated in the doc, you can configure the amount of dead letters to be logged during shutdown as follows:

```
akka {
  log-dead-letters = 10
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = on
}
```

There was also some related [router actor specific discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971088/dead-letters-encountered-as-soon-as-actors-are-placed-into-router) that might be of interest.